# Locally saved revisions with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, revision

I was searching for a plugin for *Eclipse* that will help me save revisions of my code, locally on my computer. All I found was *subversion* plugins.

Thnx,
Royi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [eGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/), it does not require any server-side infrastructure in its smallest setup. I use it for my personal stuff as well.

Comment: I guess that a silly question but does it work with all programming languages or just with Java?

Comment: In eclipse I used it with Java, JavaScript, C++. So as it is file based, it should work with all languages. Advantage is that you are not required to have a background process listening to some port.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does indeed save versions as *Local History*, but it's not as advanced as Subversion (SVN) or CVS.

If you are really interested, you can [Setup an SVN Server](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) on your own machine

Comment: Installing a private SVN server would be a great solution, and I could connect to it remotely. Since I'm not home right now (University), I'm looking for a more "local\laptop" solution.